# Azure Storage Static website Hosted Standalone Blazor WASM appsettings

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am hosting my standalone Blazor WASM app in an Azure Storage Account Static website and wondering how to handle switching between development and production API endpoints using settings in `appsettings.json`/`appsettings.staging.json`. The [documentation I've found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0) talks more about App Service hosted apps.

I cannot get [this `Blazor.start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method to work.

I must admit I haven't tried the option to inject an IConfiguration and use HttpClient but would like to check if there's a simple method.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm attempting the same thing ...

Comment: @jrummell Just posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't claim to have come up with this myself but I cannot find my reference right now. Anyway I ended up adding this method to my `Program.cs`.

##### Program.cs

```cs
private static async Task ConfigureApiEndpoint(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var http = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
            };
            string apiEndpoint = String.Empty;
            if (builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress.Contains("localhost"))
                apiEndpoint = "api-endpoint-staging.json";
            else if (builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress.Contains("mysubdomain.domain.com"))
                apiEndpoint = "api-endpoint-staging.json";
            else
                apiEndpoint = "api-endpoint-production.json";
            
            using var response = await http.GetAsync(apiEndpoint);
            using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(stream);
        }
```

##### api-endpoint-staging.json

Put this in wwwroot folder. Set as Content build action. Do not copy to output.

```json
{
  "SirenApi": {
    "BaseAddress": "https://mysubdomain.domain.com/api/"
  }
}
```